# Stop dll from being executed by exe

Tags: dll

I need to stop a dll from loading without crashing the exe (my antivirus prevent that specific dll from loading) I don't want to run that dll, I just want to "ignore" the specific error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop running specific dll, here is the instruction :

1. Go and find "Search" button in "Start" menu.
2. You should search "All files and folders," then type the name of that DLL file you want to stop running into the search dialog box.
3. Locate the DLL file and write down the full file path for the DLL file.
4. Now go to "command prompt". You find it at start menu with "cmd" name or press `Windows key + R` then type cmd.
5. Now type `cd c:\FilePathFromSearch\DLLName.dll`.
6. Then type `regsvr32 /u DLLName`. Replace the actual DLL name without the brackets for `DLLName`.

The DLL file is now no longer running on your system.

Comment: @calintomescu I have tried this on my system and it worked fine. Maybe you missed one step. Try to do it again and follow the steps. Make sure you have set restore point.

Answer (score -1):

1. First step ( open cmd ):
   At start, type CMD.  Then open with administrator access
   Or
   Press windows key + R  and then type cmd , then press Shift + Ctrl + Enter
2. Second step ( Open dll location ) :
   Example          cd c:\Program File

3.third step ( type command and press enter ) :
regsvr32 /u /s dllname.dll

Finally You succeeded.